# How do I configure multiple VPN auto-connections?

Tags: network-manager, vpn

As of recently, Ubuntu allows connections to multiple simultaneous VPNs.

However, the Network Manager (at least the GUI) still only allows for only one VPN to auto-connect:

[image]

Is there some way I can select multiple VPN configurations to connect at the same time (perhaps through the config files)?

Comment: *"connect at the same time"* - By that do you mean **1)** Run a VPN through another VPN, or **2)** Allow multiple to auto-connect, like auto connecting to Wi-FI?

Comment: I mean auto-connect, so I'm connected to both VPNs at once (not through each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI just does not have that option or capability yet. Here the bug report:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/network-manager-applet/-/issues/27

Instead, the config file contains a field called `secondaries`, which [supports multiple interfaces](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nm-settings-nmcli.html).

However, this can still be manually configured in the config file. Open a terminal, and drop into a root shell. Note that this guide assumes that you already have one of your VPN autoconnect configs set up from the GUI and already tested.

2. `cd` to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.
3. Run `ls` and find the VPN interface you want to add as another autoconnect.
4. Get the VPN for that interface using the following command:

   ```
    cat MyOtherVPN | grep uuid | cut -d "=" -f 2
   ```
5. Open the network interface you want to trigger both VPNs:

   ```
    nano MyWirelessNetwork
   ```
6. Find the `secondaries` line, and add the UUID from step 4 to the end of the line. Add a semicolon after the pasted UUID. It should look something like this:

   ```
    secondaries=f7fc14a5-a123-4054-b4ef-312d23148c59;83079486-6f69-40ec-83e6-52aaa16a3a43;
   ```
7. Save the file, and restart the NetworkManager service with the following command:

   ```
    systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
   ```

Upon reconnection to the network, all the VPNs will be enabled automagically.

You can add as many secondary connections as needed, though note that they won't show up in the GUI config.

Answer (score 2):

Create script that connects to your VPNs and place as `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/auto_vnp_up` file (set 755 permissions):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
interface=$1 status=$2
case $status in
  up|vpn-down)
    nmcli con up id "Your first VPN name"
    nmcli con up id "Your second VPN name"
    ;;
esac
```

Aware that using such approach connections to VPNs will be established asynchronously after connection to your Ethernet/Wi-fi network established.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for two reasons: (i) it works with any primary connection because it is not bound to any specific one. In most cenceivable cases you would want to have the VPNs autoconnected when there is any primary connection that is up and running. And (ii) it cannot be messed up with the GUI that can only enter one of the networks. One little nitpick: I think that the 755 permissions are excessively open. 700 with owner root does the trick just fine.